# how to put if,else endif in inside html tag laravel 5.7

Tags: html, laravel-5

**I am trying to put if else and end if in html tags (concatenation But its not working property will you help me  its because of i am new to laravel  **

```
     $output .= '
<tr>

<td>'.$row->total_price.'</td>
<td><a href="/orderview/'.$row->order_id.'"> 
  <button data-toggle="tooltip" title="View" 
     class="pd-setting-ed"><i class="fa fa-search-plus" 
     aria-hidden="true"></i></button></a> 
</td>
<td>' .(($row->aproval == 1)).' <label 
  class="switch">                               
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked"   
     onclick="aproveorder('.$row->order_id.')"> 
  <span class="slider round">&nbsp;&nbsp;Yes</span>
  </label> 
</td>
' .(($row->aproval == 0)). '<label class="switch">                                          
<input type="checkbox"  value="" id="product_status" 
  onclick="aproveorder('.$row->order_id.')"> 
<span class="slider round">&nbsp;&nbsp;Yes</span>
</label></td>
<td>    <label class="switch">                              
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="" id="" 
     onclick="deliverystatus('.$row->order_id.')"> 
  <span class="slider round">&nbsp;&nbsp;Done</span>
  </label> 
</td>
'.($row->payment_status == 0).'<label 
  class="switch">
 <input type="checkbox"  value=""  onclick="deliverystatus('.$row- 
  >order_id.')"> 
<span class="slider round">&nbsp;&nbsp;No</span>
 </label></td></td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel has 'blade'(templates) for this. I think you should use it with params:
`@each('view.name', $row)`, something like this.
Read the documentation for more: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade